# DOM updated, but its view isn’t rendering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a chat application.
I have a function that runs whenever I get a new msg to add the msg to the scope so it'll be rendered by ng-repeat.
Function looks like this:

```
var gotMsg = function(message) {
    var msg = message.message;
    var name = message.name
    console.log('scope.messages', $scope.msgCtrl.messages);
    $scope.msgCtrl.messages[name].push({
        message: msg,
        user: name
    });

    $scope.$digest();
    //scroll to bottom
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);
```

I receive the message no problem, and from running 'ionic run android' and looking from chrome inspect, I see that the DOM is updated with the new msg correctly interpolated.

However! These new messages are not rendered properly. It's either just white, or broken. It does show up when I scroll up the chat and come back down however.
What could be causing this? I've tried with/without $digest/$apply/$timeout/$eval.Async, etc. Nothing is working so far. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: `$scope.$digest();` only run digest cycle for their descendant elemet..do try `if(!$scope.$$phase)$scope.$apply();`

Comment: I will try that.. though I heard thats not a good pattern to check for $$phase to use $apply. Hmm and my issue isn't that the bindings are not updated, it's correctly in the DOM when I check with chrome inspector.. why would my view render like above?

Comment: `$scope.$apply()` must check `$$phase`,the reason behind that is, if you run apply directly, and the phase of scope is already running digest cycle  then  then it will break the code..and error will be thrown as `$digest` already in progress

Comment: as per angular running `$apply()` on scope is not good practice. Whenever you are turning away from angular, like using any jquery plugin, or any other javascript. or any async operation without angular. you have $apply() scope after completion of action..refer this document https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Comment: `$scope.$apply(function(){console.log('scope.messages', $scope.msgCtrl.messages);
    $scope.msgCtrl.messages[name].push({
        message: msg,
        user: name
    });
});` try this code it should work.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried all those and more but doesn't seem to work.. I'm starting to think this issue is with ionic. When I open the app on the browser/emulator it works fine but just not on real phones.. Also I think angular would either render it, or not render it -- but not render broken like in the pic..

Comment: `gotMsg` from where did it get call?

Comment: under a pubnub function. pubnub opens a socket so I can receive/send msgs through it. gotMsg is is called when pubnub receives a message. I'm consoling out the new msg and its shown everytime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69467/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-kostar).

Comment: are you using this http://www.pubnub.com/developers/angularjs/#/join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around to render the messages properly.
Basically needed to hide & show a DOM element that would force "movement" to the page so it would get re-rendered. 
I found the element HAS to cause a movement, and cannot be a hidden element. Also, it needed to have a bit of a delay. 0ms would not work.

```
$timeout(function() {

    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("nbsp")[0];
    el.style.display = 'none';

    $timeout(function() {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }, 50);

}, 50);
```